# Filling <string> list or array to export element names to excel

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, list, revit-api

The goal is to fill excel cells with elements names. Using EPPlus.

**_elementsDB** gives just "Autodesk.Revit.DB.Wall".

```
int col = 1;
for ( int row=2; row < _elementsDB.Count; row++ )
{                
ws.Cells[row, col].Value = _elementsDB;
}
```

Tying to populate either an array or list. Nothing works.

```
FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
IList<Element> _elementsDB = collector.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements();
List<Element> _elementsDB = collector.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements();

//First Option
string[] _elementsNameArr = new string[] { };
foreach (Element e in _elementsDB)
{

    _elementsNameArr = e.Name;
}

//Second Option
List <string> _elementsNameList = new List<string>;
foreach (Element e in _elementsDB)
{

    _elementsNameList = e.Name;
}
```

Also tried to create a sorted list, didn't work either. Shows up an excxeption System.Argument.Exception "A record with such a key already exists".

```
SortedList<string, Element> _elementNameSorted = new SortedList<string, Element>();

            foreach (Element e in _elementsDB)
            {
                _elementNameSorted.Add(e.Name,e);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the method `.ToElements()` it returns a `IList<Element>` that you can convert it later, you cannot directly assign its result to `List<Element>`, you have to use LINQ to convert, using `.ToElements().ToList()`

If you don't have it yet, be sure to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your code.

Anyway, there's no need to convert to `List<Element>` here, try the code below:

```
FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
IList<Element> _elementsDB = collector.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements();
//List<Element> _elementsDB = collector.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements(); // <---- IF YOU ALREADY DECLARED _elementsDB BEFORE, YOU CAN'T HAVE THIS HERE TOGETHER

List <string> _elementsNameList = new List<string>(); // <-- YOU'VE MISSED () HERE
foreach (Element e in _elementsDB)
{
    _elementsNameList.Add(e.Name); // <-- HERE YOU HAVE TO ADD IT TO THE LIST, NOT ASSIGN TO THE LIST, YOU CANNOT ASSIGN A string TO A List<string>, YOU HAVE TO ADD
}

//Sorting your list would be
_elementsNameList = _elementsNameList.OrderBy(q => q).ToList();

//...... Write here if you have any code before writing the Excel

try
{
    WriteXLS("YOU EXCEL FILE PATH HERE", "YOUR WORKSEET NAME HERE", _elementsNameList, 2); // <--- METHOD SOWN IN THE CODE BELOW
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    TaskDialog.Show("Error", e.Message);
}
```

For writing to an existing Excel file you can use the method bellow:

```
private void WriteXLS(string filePath, string workSheetName, List<string> elementsNamesList, int startRow = 1, int col = 1)
{
    FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(filePath);
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws = GetWorkSheet(package, workSheetName);
        int maxRows = elementsNamesList.Count;
        for (int row = startRow; row <= maxRows; row++)
        {
            ws.Cells[row, col].Value = elementsNamesList[row];
        }
    }
}
```

And, before running it, be sure to have you Excel file closed, it doesn't work if the file is opened.